# Running out of L:/ etters: shortcut for path needed

Tags: customize, find-file

I'm working with files which are stored on a server. The structure on the server is:

```
//SBS/share/path/to/somewhere/2007/
//SBS/share/path/to/somewhere/2008/
//SBS/share/path/to/somewhere/2009/
...
//SBS/share/path/to/somewhere/2015/
```

In every years folder are the folders of the year, sometimes up to 1000.

Emacs 24.4 is running on a Win 7 machine. I used to map the folders of the years with letters (`X:`), but I'm running out of letters now, 2015 is mapped to `Z:`.

If I wish to open a file of the year 2015, I do: `C-x C-f`, delete whatever appears in the minibuffer, type `Z:`, followed by the first letters of the folder. Without mapping the share to Z:, I'd have to type much more:
    //SBS/share/path/to/somewhere/2015/

Emacs can't handle the Windows shortcuts `*.lnk`. Windows can't map more shares than 26.

My general idea is that I could customise the command "find file" (C-x C-f) somehow.

What I'd like to have that I just type something like C-x C-f 2015 and get 
in the minibuffer the line:

```
Find file: //SBS/share/path/to/somewhere/2015/
```

with the cursor on the point after the last "/" and the usual auto-complition working, so that typing `foo` will be completed to `foo.tex`, if this exists (or a folder called foo).

Comment: Perhaps [`ido-mode`](http://www.masteringemacs.org/article/introduction-to-ido-mode)?

Comment: @Dan How could that spare typing a long path? Auto-completion is definitely helpfull, but typing just `2015` would be much faster...

Comment: Bookmarks? `C-x r m` and `C-x r b`

Comment: @phils combining that with `helm-bookmarks` might work well for him.

Comment: I don't understand why you aren't assigning `//SBS/share/path/to/somewhere` itself a letter. Or, still solving this in Windows rather than Emacs, using reparse points.

Comment: +1, sounds like bookmarks named 2015 etc would meet your needs. Also would be handy to expand bookmarks from the (ido-)find-file prompt -- I used to use something for that....

Comment: Or use something like this: http://whattheemacsd.com/setup-ido.el-02.html to define a key that inserts the full base path in your find-file prompt. Then you could type e.g. C-x C-f ` 2015/foo.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I'd echo the suggestion of using bookmarks.
2. You can use environment variables (define your own, to correspond to whatever directory prefixes you want).
3. You can define directory abbreviations, using option `directory-abbrev-alist`. That's what it is for. See the Emacs manual, node [`File Aliases`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Aliases.html).

   The doc focuses on the use of `directory-abbrev-alist` with symbolic links, but you can use it for any directory abbreviations.

   Vanilla Emacs does not *complete* your directory abbreviations, but [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles) does. (RMS gave as the reason that vanilla Emacs should not do this: "*I don’t think Emacs should alter the names that the user enters.*"

   Here is the doc string for option `directory-abbrev-alist`:

   ```
   directory-abbrev-alist is a variable defined in `files.el'.
   Its value is nil

   Documentation:
   Alist of abbreviations for file directories.
   A list of elements of the form (FROM . TO), each meaning to replace
   FROM with TO when it appears in a directory name.  This replacement is
   done when setting up the default directory of a newly visited file.

   FROM is matched against directory names anchored at the first
   character, so it should start with a "\\`", or, if directory
   names cannot have embedded newlines, with a "^".

   FROM and TO should be equivalent names, which refer to the
   same directory.  Do not use `~' in the TO strings;
   they should be ordinary absolute directory names.

   Use this feature when you have directories which you normally refer to
   via absolute symbolic links.  Make TO the name of the link, and FROM
   the name it is linked to.

   You can customize this variable.
   ```

   So as an example, you might have an entry like this in `directory-abbrev-alist`:

```el
    (\`2015 . //SBS/share/path/to/somewhere/2015)
```

Then if you use `C-x C-f 2015 TAB` (in **Icicles**) your input of `2015` is completed to `//SBS/share/path/to/somewhere/2015`, and you can type more to complete to something in that directory.

And if you had an entry like this (same thing, but with a trailing `/`):

```el
    (\`2015 . //SBS/share/path/to/somewhere/2015/)
```

Then `C-x C-f 2015 TAB` shows you all of the files in that directory as completion candidates.

Comment: I'll try bookmarks. Low effort, nothing more than I need.

Answer (score 1):

You open these files frequently so the paths will be in history. Use <kbd>C-x C-f C-r 2015</kbd> to bring the last file you opened with 2015 in it's path into the mini-buffer and use normal completion from there. Pressing <kbd>C-r</kbd> again will get the next to last used path with `2015`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate method you could use symbolic links in Windows 7 to map your network shares to folders (and thus spare your Drive Letters).  (Source: [SuperUser: How to mount a network drive to a folder](https://superuser.com/questions/244562/how-to-mount-a-network-drive-to-a-folder) )

Suppose you have folder `c:\yearly\` to store the various year folders

```
mklink /D c:\yearly\2015 \\SBS\share\path\to\somewhere\2015
```

Then you can directly use: `C:\yearly\2015\...` as your path to access the files.

I've tested this on a desktop with a fixed access to the destination server.  A laptop may run into connection issues (due to lack of availability of the folder).

Note:  This will not work on WindowsXP without a third party tool.  `mklink` was only introduced in Vista.

Comment: I'm on Win 7. I'm surprised mklink works with shares, I thought this worked only for local folders.

Comment: Without the `/D` it won't necessarily work.  Hard Links `/H` will not work (can't share the node on another device) and Junctions `/J` don't behave properly when going to the network.  I think that without the `/D` it tries to default to Junction, which is why it will fail.